# Which Facebook application security Settings shall I disable / enable

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm using Facebook SDK in my Android application, I count on the FB SDK to get user logged into my application and grant my application needed permissions, and I know that FB SDK offers the user a login dialog whether Android Facebook application is installed or not.

**My question simply is, which options should I enable / disable based on the info I provided above to get my application secured as much as possible?**

P.S: As I have no experience on web programming or dealing with sending / receiving data from servers, and no experience in creating OAuth flows, so these options are confusing to me.

P.S -2: I set these options in the picture based on Facebook security tool check recommendation to secure my app, and based on reading [Login Security](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/security)

[Facebook Login Security options (Click here to see the options picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y1W6.png)

**And what confused me more**, that though I disabled all (**Client OAuth Settings**), the Facebook security check tool informs me:

```
**State Parameter Used on Embedded Browser OAuth Login:**
*It looks like you're using an embedded browser OAuth login flow. Use a state parameter to guard against cross-site request forgery. See the documentation for more information.*
```

Knowing that I haven't yet submitted these new changes to be reviewed by Facebook.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the documentation says:

Disable client OAuth Login if you are not using Facebook Login in SDK to get the user logged in into your app

Disable Web OAuth Login if you are not planning to provide web related login services for your app

Disable Embedded Browser OAuth Login if you do not do any login flow in a webview in your app

Comment: I'm not that good in English, so could you simplify this phrase "Disable client OAuth Login if you are not using Facebook Login in SDK to get the user logged in into your app" ... Because I use Facebook SDK to get user logged into my Android application and to grant permissions, so if I disable ' Client OAuth' will my application users still be able to loginto my app and use it?

Comment: If you are using Facebook Login then keep it enabled only

Comment: Also if you disable this option, your users can still log into your app if you have a facebook app and single sign on enabled otherwise they cannot log in. It gives an error saying your application has disabled client OAuth login flow